# Whose hands are these in Assassination Classroom chapter 179?

Tags: assassination-classroom

In chapter 179 of *Assassination Classroom*, there are 2 panels showing hands holding each other:

[image: Assassination Classroom Ch 179 pg 16]

My hunch is that there's no distinctive evidence (unless there is some from the anime or movie or something) as to leave it perhaps to the reader to interpret as they like to avoid backlash. Though I feel there have been a fair amount of hints pointing towards Kayano and Nagisa if I got the names right (Kiss, valentines, the poster in the top left panel is of her). Though there could be evidence against it as well that I am not aware of.

Whose hands are these?

Answer (score 1):

The poster and the scene afterward featuring Kayano strongly implies the female hand is hers.

It would sense that the person she was holding hands with someone that wasn't present at the old classroom building at the time, assuming that all the vignettes were happening more or less in real time.

The most likely conclusion would be that the male hand belongs to Nagisa.

After being questioned by Hara, Kayano didn't deny that they weren't together, and only mentions that he's focusing on his teaching career.

The anime skips this scene so there is no decisive conclusion, only speculation.

Comment: Still, Kayano is shown few pages later having sleeves on hands, which partially cover her palms, while there was no sleeves on hand on picture above.

Comment: She could easily put them on and take them off, which she does in the following chapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

First, we remember that the team was supposed to meet at the station, and the ones holding hands seems to be with them too. And we also must consider that Kayano was already there when the team arrived at the campus.

So, we have Maehara, Isogai, Fuwa, Kataoka, Okajima, Yada, Kimura, Chiba, Hayami, Hara and Mimura.

Then, we could add that, as you can see, both wrists aren't covered by any sleeve; yes, they could have rolled up their sleeves, but it wouldn't make much sense. So, it excludes Kataoka, Chiba, maybe Fuwa (though we can't see where her sleeves reach) and makes even more sure that the feminine hand isn't Kayano's.

Moreover, I'm not sure about Isogai, because, as we can see, his hands are both occupied; but he could have laid the bag or the broom in the station. Yes, it wouldn't make so much sense, but I'm considering every possibility.

In the end, the only possible popular ships it could be are Isogai/Kataoka and Kimura/Yada; although, Isogai has the problem we first said, and Yada canonically likes girls (it's stated that she had a crush on Kataoka), so I personally think it's a ship that we never saw, like, I don't know, Fuwa and Mimura, or Hara and Okajima, or anyone you want.